# How to show keyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have UITableView where each cell consists of two UILabel, I want to show up keyboard when the cell is selected? Is it possible with UILabels?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to pop up a keyboard, you can add a tiny invisible (transparent 1x1 with transparent text) UITextField anywhere in any visible view and make this text field first responder to pop up a keyboard.  Then you can redirect the input text to any of the two labels (or somewhere else) using the text field delegates to capture the input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the label has to conform to the [UIKeyInput protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  Note that this is an either-or proposition.  If the label conforms to UIKeyInput, then when it becomes first responder, the keyboard will be displayed, whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you mean this exactly since it is obviously not possible to edit two textfields for labels at the same time. Hence the following assumes you want to show the text in your cell using UILabel, but want to be able to edit the cell's text.

You can't directly use the keyboard to edit UILabels. The easiest solution is to directly use UITextFields instead of the UILabels.

An alternative is to have both a `UITextField` and `UILabel` in the cell. Then show the textfield (by settings itsß `hidden property to`YES`) when the cell is selected and hide the label. When editing is finished, do the reverse (i.e. showing labels, hiding textfields).

To show the keyboard directly after selecting the cell you can call `[someTextField becomeFirstResponder];`. To check if the user is done editing (and e.g. tapped the return key), you can set the `delegate` of the `UITextField`.