# Set text inputed from keypad on UILabel on UIButton click

Tags: ios, iphone

i want to write the text to UILabel which is inputed from iphone's keypad. when i tapped button as in screen shot. how i can do that ? i don't want to use Textfield.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641175/how-to-show-keyboard-programatically

Comment: What's wrong with the `UITextField`?

Comment: @Rushabh Seeing as your links and trying...!!

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction) buttonTapped {
    [self.yourlabel setText:[textField text]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `UITextField` (you can name it `hiddenTextField`) some where, and set it hidden in view, so it'll become invisible to everyone, in `viewDidLoad` method of that `UIViewController` write,

```
[hiddenTextField becomeFirstResponder]; //it will make UIKeyBoard show on screen
```

On your `UIButton` action write,

```
- (IBAction)myAction {
    myLabel.text = hiddenTextField.text;

    //Don't forget to set `hiddenTextField` delegate to self.
    [hiddenTextField resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```